# Is there a way to print all SQL statements performed by JDBC?

Tags: java, debugging, jdbc

Without changing anything in my code is there a way to tell JDBC to print any query executed by  Statement#executeUpdate(...) and  Statement#execute(...)?

It would be really useful for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried all of your suggestion but at the end I've found log4jdbc and I used it

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/ and http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-remix/

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use a wrapper around the actual driver like [P6Spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/). There are probably other tools in the same league.

EDIT: P6Spy seems to be dead. But I also found [JDBCGrabber](http://code.google.com/p/jdbcgrabber/).

Comment: P6Spy is really great even if not maintained anymore. It's definitively the answer to your question. If ok, do not forget to validate JB Nizet's answer.

Comment: JDBCGrabber seems nice but db2 seems not to support the urser\password in the url..so I can't get it work

Answer (score 1):

This heavily depends on your jdbc driver. Most drivers allow to enable some sort of tracing. Check your driver documentation on that.

E.g.

Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm

DB2: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506fechner/

Comment: I'm using DB2 but I didn't succeed with that guide :/. I just want to print out the queries